# How to connect newly created firebase project to existing Google Analytics property (instead of creating a new GA Property)

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have an existing ios app that is using Firebase & Google Analytics. This is version 1. It's working and I can see analytics data in Firebase & GA.

I'm working on version 2 and trying to connect it to the existing Google Analytics acct with another property. Is this possible?

It seems GA has changed their setup since a year+ ago and it is suggesting for me to create a new property in GA, select 'mobile app', then connect to the firebase project. BUT I don't want to create a new property -- I just want to link it to an already existing property

Do I have to create a new account and lose the existing data? Or can I just plug in the Google Analytics number somewhere in Version 2 (I can't find a place for that).

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Was going to ask the same thing.